# Stochastic domination by coupling

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

The following is a slightly streamlined version of Exercise 7.5 in Dubashi & Panconesi's "Concentration of Measure for the Analysis of Random Algorithms":

> Let $X$ and $Z$ be independent random variables with $X\in[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{E}X \le \mathbb{E}Z$. Use a coupling argument to show that $\mathbb{P}(X>t) \le \mathbb{P}(Z>t)$ for all $t$.

A counter-example would seem to be: 
  $$\mathbb{P}(X=0)=\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1/2\\\mathbb{P}(Z=0)=2/3,\mathbb{P}(Z=3)=1/3\\t=1/2.$$

Am I missing something obvious? A previous exercise has you assume $Z\in[0,1]$ also. In this case I'm still not clear how to find a monotone coupling when $X$ and $Z$ have potentially different distributions (not obvious how to generalize the standard example of coupling two Bernoullis). Any hints would be appreciated. This is for self-study. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "independently distributed"?

Comment: The statement is obviously wrong, even assuming that $0\leqslant Z\leqslant1$ almost surely.

Comment: @saz The usual definition of independence. Edited to make the wording more standard.

Comment: The paraphrasing probably has an error. Here is a  screenshot from the relevant page of the book:http://i.stack.imgur.com/VeWIr.jpg

Comment: Okay, I can see why this is true. (In my defense, it seems like they have corrected the error in a new edition. My copy makes no mention of the fact that the variables must be Poisson.)